# From diagonalizing bases for matrices A and B, how do I find one basis that diagonalizes both matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

The first matrix A has eigenvectors

(0,1,0), (2,0,1), (1,0,1)

The second matrix B has eigenvectors

(4,1,2), (1,1,0), (1,0,1).

Both sets form a basis for $R^3$.

Now, how do I pick out a basis of eigenvectors that simultaneously diagonalizes A and B?

I've searched on MSE but have only found proof-y discussions of this topic, but I want to find an explicit basis.

Thanks,

EDIT:  I tried putting all six vectors in a matrix, each in a row, and row reduced until I got 3 linearly independent vectors.  I used this as S, computed the inverse, but then $S^{-1}AS$ is not diagonal anymore...almost diagonal, though - off by one non-zero entry, with all of A's eigenvalues *still* on the diagonal.  So, I'm pretty close, I think.

EDIT 2:

The matrices are:

$$ A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & 3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$ B= 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 4 & 4 \\
        -1 & 5 & 1 \\
        -2 & 2 & 6 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Eigenvalues for A are 1,2 -- with 1 having geometric multiplicity = 2.

Eigenvalues for B are 3, 4 -- with 4 having geometric multiplicity = 2.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I think it only works for symmetric matrices. I'll rethink it and let you know.

Comment: Ah, ok, got it.  Thanks for the quick response, @joriki.  I will do some more work on this before moving on to new problems.  And unfortunately, I have not seen discussions on this topic on MSE that talk about finding an explicit basis -- the questions and answers I have found are mainly proving the claim of simultaneous diagonalizability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $A$ has the eigenspaces (according to your computation)
$$
E_1(A)=span\left( \pmatrix{0\\1\\0}, \pmatrix{2\\0\\1}\right),
E_2(A)=span \pmatrix{1\\0\\1},
$$
while $B$ has the eigenspaces 
$$
E_4(B)=span\left( \pmatrix{1\\1\\0}, \pmatrix{1\\0\\1}\right),
E_3(B)=span \pmatrix{4\\1\\2}.
$$
The goal is to find a basis of common eigenvectors. That is, to find vectors that are in eigenspaces of $A$ and of $B$.

Clearly, $\pmatrix{1\\0\\1} \in E_2(A)\cap E_4(B)$, 
$\pmatrix{4\\1\\2}\in E_1(A)\cap E_3(B)$, $\pmatrix{2\\1\\1}\in E_1(A)\cap E_4(B)$.

Moreover, these vectors are linearly independent, and as such from a basis of eigenvectors of both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Very pretty and simple answer @daw -- thanks so much.  I have noticed a restriction, though:  in picking the third eigenvector from the two-dimensional eigenspaces, the vector must be (of course) expandable in a linear combination of the two vectors that span the two-dimensional eigenspace -- but in the linear combination, the coefficients must both be non-zero.

Comment: Otherwise, I am guessing that it is like picking an eigenvector that corresponds to an eigevalue having geometric multiplicity = 1, which then makes both A and B not diagonalizable, since the algebraic and geometric multiplicities must match for all eigenvalues of a matrix for it to be diagonalizable.